# Entity Framework - Blank data is still added to Database

Tags: database, entity-framework, null

I have made a validation to prevent data into being inserted to the DB when it's empty but it still enters a blank form to the database?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProjectTestEntities User_save = new ProjectTestEntities();
        User ins = new User();

        ins.name = TextBox1.Text;
        ins.email = TextBox2.Text;
        ins.phone = TextBox3.Text;
        ins.gender = RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue;
        ins.password = TextBox4.Text;

        if (ins.name == null || ins.email == null || ins.gender == null || ins.password == null)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Incomplete input";
        }
        else
        {
            User_save.Users.AddObject(ins);
            User_save.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ins.name == null) || 
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(ins.email == null) ||
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(ins.gender == null) ||
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(ins.password == null))
{
    Label1.Text = "Incomplete input";
}
else
{
    User_save.Users.AddObject(ins);
    User_save.SaveChanges();
}
```